# On live server password reset link is not redirecting to reset password page using django-rest-framework and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, react-router, django-serializer

On Live Server: here I am sending mail to forgot the password, I receive mail but when I clicked the password reset link its not redirect to the Password Reset Page.

showing

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKEEA.png)]

but when I am using localhost it works fine it's redirecting to the Password Reset Page.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgEw.png)]

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import "./App.css";
import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
 Routes,
 Route,
 Navigate
} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./Home"
import LoginReg from './pages/auth/LoginReg';
import SendPasswordResetEmail from './pages/auth/SendPasswordResetEmail';
import ResetPassword from './pages/auth/ResetPassword';

const App = () => {
 const { access_token } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

 return (
   <div >
     <Router>
       <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/">
           <Route index element={<Home />} />
         </Route>
  
         {/* Login and registration path for Admin/User credential */} 
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Layout />}>
           <Route
             path="loginreg"
             element={access_token
               ? <Navigate to='/dashboard' />
               : <LoginReg />
             }
           />
           <Route
             path="sendpasswordresetemail"
             element={<SendPasswordResetEmail />}
           />
           <Route
             path="api/user/reset/:id/:token"
             element={<ResetPassword />}
           />
           <Route path="passwordchange" element={<ChangePassword />} />
         </Route>
         <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
       </Routes>
     </Router>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Serializer.py

```py
class SendPasswordResetEmailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print("attrs:",attrs)
        email = attrs.get('email')
        print("email:", email)
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(email = email)
            print("User:",user)
            # encode karenge user id ko or 
            uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id))
             print('Encoded UID', uid)
            token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)
            print('Password Reset Token', token)
            link = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/reset/'+uid+'/'+str(token)
            print('Password Reset Link', link)
        #  Send EMail
            body = 'Click Following Link to Reset Your Password Local '+link
            data = {
            'subject':'Reset Your Password',
            'body':body,
            'to_email': user.email
            }
           print("Data:", data)
            Util.send_email(data)             
            return attrs
    
        raise serializers.ValidationError('You are not a Registered User')`
```